# Unable to connect to powermeter through Ethernet-GPIB adapter

Tags: python-3.x, gpib, pyvisa

When i am trying to run my code i get the following error :
ValueError: Please install linux-gpib to use this resource type.
No module named 'gpib'

After trying to install linux-gpib, using pip and the command line, i get this one :
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement linux-gpib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for linux-gpib

I have managed to connect a signal generator through ethernet but i got no luck using the same principles with gpib.

Tried to reinstall python and the pyvisa package with no luck, tried importing a wrapper for this specific ethernet adapter :
pip install git+git://github.com/nelsond/prologix-gpib-ethernet.git
again no luck.
I also tried using the ip provided by the adapter driver to connect through TCPIP, still no luck.

```py
import visa

rm = visa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
inst = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::16::INSTR') #using GPIB
inst = rm.open_resource('TCPIP::192.168.1.77::INSTR') #using TCPIP
print(inst.query("*IDN?"))
```

The executed code should provide the IDN of the device, eg :
Rohde & Schwarz,SMB100A,1406.6000k02...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to another USB to GPIB adapter.